# How to stop for each loop running on web elements list in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I created a method that run on web elements list, and return the index of the expected value in the list.
the method evaluate the get attribute value with expected value.
It is working OK, however it is running until the end of the list. is the only option is to break the loop is to enter break; after index = iterator

```
  public Integer indexInList(String expectedValue,List<WebElement> dropdownOptions,String attributeValue) throws Exception {
        Integer index = -1;  // -1 meanning not found in list
        int iterator = 0;    // run on the list

        for (WebElement element : dropdownOptions )

        {
            if(element.getAttribute(attributeValue).equals(expectedValue))
            {
                index = iterator;


            }
            iterator ++;
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: just return iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you need enter break after the line index=iterator

Answer (score 0):

Return the iterator when `for` loop finds desired element:

```
  public Integer indexInList(String expectedValue,List<WebElement> dropdownOptions,String attributeValue) throws Exception {
        int iterator = 0;    // run on the list

        for (WebElement element : dropdownOptions )
        {
            if(element.getAttribute(attributeValue).equals(expectedValue))
            {
                return iterator;
            }
            iterator ++;
        }

        return -1; // -1 meanning not found in list
    }
```

The above is slight modification of your code. You don't need the `index` variable, you can operate on `iterator`.

Return the `iterator` when the desired element is found and it will stop `for` loop.
If none of the elements satisfies the condition, return `-1`

Answer (score 0):

No.

Apart from "enter `break;` after index = iterator", you can use `return index;` to replace the statement `break;` in the same position.